# How to make selected tab scroll to the middle in horizontal scroll view: Android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, tabwidget

I am using a TabWidget wrapped inside a horizontalscrollview.

When a user selects a particular tab, I would like to have it scroll to the centre of the tab widget part of the screen.

could someone please help?

thanks.
sunny

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) what you are looking for?

Comment: no that won't help as i am using a tabhost as there are some limitations of using viewpager